# Nokia SDK 2.0 Emulator Won't Accept Inputs from Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, emulation, nokia-s40

I am developing app for Nokia first time. I have downloaded `Nokia SDK 2.0 for Java` (for s40 series). Soft keypad opens fine, but when I am trying to give input from my PC keyboard, emulator is not accepting any key.

Can anyone tell me from where I need to change the setting? Thanks.

Comment: Please, add more details about your environment. Is it Windows 7? 64 bits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the beta SDK does not allow key inputs from PC keyboard i have just confirmed. Currently nokia is working on solution. So best solution is to test on device.

Confirmation link is [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?237244-Nokia-SDK-2.0%28Beta%29-Emulator-Won-t-Accept-Inputs-from-Keyboard&p=902053#post902053)

Answer (score 0):

If Nokia SDK 2.0(Beta) is not working then test your application by on device debugging.